# how to sort an array by the value outputted by similar_text function php

Tags: php, html

i have this code that asks for an input, takes that input, compares it with all the values in a database and assigns a number to it.

```
if(isset($_GET['subreddit']) && empty($_GET['subreddit'])){
?>
<form method="post">
    <input type="search" name="subsearch">
</form>
<?php
$sql = "SELECT subname FROM subreddits";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $a=array();
    array_push($a, $row["subname"]);
    if(isset($_POST['subsearch'])){
        $c=0;
        foreach ($a as $value){
            $value2 =$_POST['subsearch'];
            $sim = similar_text($value, $value2 , $perc);
            echo $value."   ".$sim. "<br>";
        }
    }
}
die();}
```

I want to sort the array $a by the number the similar_text() function outputs.

Comment: You will probably be best off doing the search via the sql query using the `LIKE` operator, example: https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-like/

Comment: `LIKE` isn't really a competitor to `similar_text`; its more like `levenshtein`. I agree doing this kinda stuff in the DB is generally better, but i don't think mysql comes with these functions (by default), i think postgres does, but chances are he's using mysql.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add it to a new `$z` array with `$sim . '_' . $value . '_' . $index` as the key, then sort `$z` with `ksort()`;.

String values with padded 0's are necessary for sorting because both `$sim` and `$value` could have duplicates. The appended `$index` makes sure the duplicate values aren't lost.

It seems excessive, but 2 foreach loops are required to get the largest string length of `$sim` for efficiently padding the keys.

```
end($a);
$aLength = strlen(key($a));
$largestSimLength = 1;
$y = $z = array();

foreach ($a as $value) {
    $sim = similar_text($value, $_POST['subsearch'] , $perc);
    $simLength = strlen($sim);
    $y[] = $sim;

    if ($simLength > $largestSimLength) {
        $largestSimLength = $simLength;
    }
}

foreach ($a as $index => $value) {
    $z[str_pad($y[$index], $largestSimLength, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . '_' . $value . '_' . str_pad($index, $aLength, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)] = $value;
}

ksort($z);
print_r($z);
```

Comment: It doesn't work if `similar_text` returns more than 9 for some of your items because `10_` is before `9_` for `sort`.

Comment: Yes padding with zeros is a possible way, you can also build the key with `sprintf` with justifications. `pack` is also interesting. Or build a number to keep the comparison numerical (you shift the similar_text number 16 bits, or less,  on the left and you add the index.

Comment: I'd pad `$sim` with leading 0's based on the largest value of `$sim`.

Comment: For instance `$z[ ($sim << 16) + $index]= $value;` (assuming the number of index < 65536, if it isn't the case, you can shift more than 16 bits).

Comment: I updated my answer. Numeric sorting doesn't work because the purpose of the `$index` is to preserve duplicate `$sim` values.

Comment: This is exactly what it does.